# iOS ibeacon identifier in initWithProximityUUID:(NSUUID *)proximityUUID identifier:(NSString *)identifier?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, identifier

I am following the following tutorial:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/

However, i'm not using an iPhone as a beacon, but i'm using real beacons from manufacturers(RECO, Estimote).

I don't understand what to use for the identifier field in the following line:

```
// Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting //beacon
self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"what should I use here?"];
```

I can modify the UUID, Major and Minor values of the beacons, but there is no option for modifying the identifier. What is the identifier?

Answer (score 1):

That string identifier is **just a unique key** for you to use to identify the region.  **You can put whatever value in the string that you want**, so long as you use the same one to identify the region again when you want to replace the region being ranged/monitored, or stop ranging/monitoring on that region.

The following example will start monitoring two regions (based on two different UUIDs, with two different identifiers "first_region" and "second_region":

```
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion: 
    [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:first_uuid 
                            identifier:@"first_region"]];

[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion: 
    [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:second_uuid
                            identifier:@"second_region"]];
```

You can then stop monitoring for the *second* region with code like this:

```
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion: 
    [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:second_uuid
                            identifier:@"second_region"]];
```

**What is important in the line of code above is this "second_region" identifier string.**  To stop monitoring correctly, **it must match the string you used to start monitoring** that region.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only one region, then you can give any string value for it as below; For more information see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566695/1351327

```
static NSString * const kIdentifier = @"SomeIdentifier";
static NSString * const kUUID = @"124C5678-4444-1111-2222-134556728422";

// Then create the region

NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:kUUID];
CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID identifier:kIdentifier];
```